# Not able to figure out why the oracle database is taking more time for insert All

Tags: database, oracle, database-performance

I am facing one issue with `insert` statements in `Oracle`.

I have to insert 200K records in the database for this I am creating a batch of  100 records per `insert` statement.
 As **Insert ALL into *tablename (columnnames....)* values *(Values...)***

but the performance is same as before while executing single insert for each row.
And after  10 batches of 100 records the execution gets slower and slower as the count of records are increased.

Please suggest me any good solution to boost performance of the orcle database.

I am using `oracle 11G`.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

thanks and regards

Comment: Why are you cutting this up? Insert all records at once, much more efficient.

Comment: and use BULK COLLECT and FORALL

Comment: If the performance gets worse after just a thousand records, I think you got issues, which could be related to contention, missing or poor indexes, triggers running heavy checks and who knows what. `Insert all` should be fast (as should `forall`,  which sandman proposed), and 1000 records should be peanuts for Oracle. Unfortunately the details are missing from the question, so it's gonna be tough to guess what the actual issue is here.